# cudf instllation issue on centos7

Tags: python-3.x, rapids, cudf

I'm new to rapids ai libraries. I've an existing conda environment yaml file where I'm using python 3.8.5, tensorflow 2.7.0, opencv-python-headless 4.5.5.62, numpy 1.22.2, pandas 1.4.1, pandas-profiling 3.1.0, seaborn 0.11.2,  matplotlib 3.5.1, jupyterlab 3.2.9.

I've added below 2 channels to the file:

- rapidsai
- nvidia

And the below packages:

- cudf=22.02
- cudatoolkit=11.5

The installation is going on for hours and while trying to find incompatible packages, it seems to be in some sort of loop as I keep seeing below message multiple times in the terminal:

Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.

Is there any known issue/limitations that I should be aware of?

Since we don't get interactive shell on GPU h/w easily, I'm trying the conda environment update on non-GPU machine and once installed, I'll try cudf package on GPU machine.

EDIT1:
This is what I have as working without tensorflow and tensorflow-hub

```yaml
    name: cudf-env
        channels:
          - default
          - rmg
          - rapidsai
          - nvidia
          - numba
          - conda-forge
          - anaconda
        dependencies:
          - glibc=2.19
          - libgcc-ng=11.2.0
          - python=3.8.5
          - cudf=22.02
          - cudatoolkit=11.2
          - pytest=6.1.2
          - pandas=1.3.5
          - numpy=1.21.5
          - requests=2.25.0
          - scikit-learn=0.24.2
          - dill=0.3.4
          - tqdm=4.62.3
          - ruamel.yaml=0.17.19
          - yappi=1.3.3
          - black=22.1.0
          - pillow=9.0.1
          - jupyterlab=3.2.9
          - matplotlib=3.5.1
          - seaborn=0.11.2
          - plotly=5.6.0
          - pandas-profiling=3.1.0
          - black=22.1.0
        #  - pip
        #  - pip:
        #      - tensorflow==2.7.0
        #      - tensorflow-hub==0.12.0
        #      - opencv-python-headless==4.5.5.62
        #      - opencv-contrib-python-headless==4.5.5.62
```

Now, if I uncomment the pip section, the anaconda crashes while creating the environment. Since pip may not be supported with cudf, I tried following as well, the `conda create env` hangs while solving the environment (strangely, it's not resolving from conda-forge channel):

```yaml
    name: cudf-env
        channels:
          - default
          - rmg
          - rapidsai
          - nvidia
          - numba
          - conda-forge
          - anaconda
        dependencies:
          - glibc=2.19
          - libgcc-ng=11.2.0
          - python=3.8.5
          - cudf=22.02
          - cudatoolkit=11.2
          - pytest=6.1.2
          - pandas=1.3.5
          - numpy=1.21.5
          - requests=2.25.0
          - scikit-learn=0.24.2
          - dill=0.3.4
          - tqdm=4.62.3
          - ruamel.yaml=0.17.19
          - yappi=1.3.3
          - black=22.1.0
          - pillow=9.0.1
          - jupyterlab=3.2.9
          - matplotlib=3.5.1
          - seaborn=0.11.2
          - plotly=5.6.0
          - pandas-profiling=3.1.0
          - black=22.1.0
          - tensorflow
          - tensorflow-hub
```

My system details are following:

```yaml
$ cat /etc/os-release
NAME="CentOS Linux"
VERSION="7 (Core)"

$ uname -r
3.10.0-1127.10.1.el7.x86_64
```

EDIT2: I forgot to mention that if I comment out glibc, cudf and cudatoolkit, the tensorflow installation through pip works fine.

Comment: Does this occur if you use `conda create ...` to create a fresh environment with cuDF rather than try to update your existing environment? Updating conda environments can be very tricky with complex dependency interactions

Comment: @NickBecker - when I create a fresh environment with just python 3.8.5, cudf and cudatoolkit, it goes through. I had to add glibc=2.19 and libgcc-ng=11.2.0 to do that. But when I add just numpy 1.22.2, pandas 1.4.1 to that, it goes on forever in scanning to find incompatible libraries.

Comment: Thanks for verifying and repeating that you're using pandas 1.4.1 (I missed that initially). I'll explain what's happening in an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Challenges updating conda environments can be tricky to untangle, but in this case the issue (in terms of cuDF) is likely the pinning of pandas to 1.4.1.

cuDF does not yet support `pandas=1.4.1`. The cuDF nightly packages currently support `pandas >=1.0,<1.4.0dev0` (everything from 1.0 up to a dev build of 1.4.0). For the moment, if you switch to
`pandas=1.3.5` things will work (assuming the other packages are compatible -- Tensorflow likely will require CUDA Toolkit 11.2, not 11.5, and some others might not be either). You can also let conda solve for the appropriate pandas version.

Comment: It seems numpy 1.22.2 is also not compatible. Compatible version is 1.21.5 - can these 2 (pandas and numpy) be documented? I'm still trying with other packages. I'll update further with my findings.

Comment: What are compatible versions of tensorflow and tensorflow-hub? I was using 2.7.0 and 0.12.0 respectively but those gave incompatible version error. I then removed the version numbers to let it chose. Now conda is still solving environment for more than an hour.

Comment: Perhaps you can provide a minimal, reproducible example of the command you are using and the system on which you're running?

Comment: The overnight run could not resolve it. I'll share the minimal reproducible example and the system details.

Comment: Please refer to the EDIT1 section in the original post.

Comment: I am finally able to install all my required packages with cudf after reimaging the machine with Ubuntu20.04.

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to complete the installation of cudf along with all the required packages after I reimaged my machine to Ubuntu20.04.

And I dropped below 2 packages as with Ubuntu20.04 I don't need those -

```
 - glibc=2.19
 - libgcc-ng=11.2.0
```